# Constant Delay in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) data transmission

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to evaluate the suitability of some different wireless interfaces for our project on 2xRaspberry Pi 4 and currently I’m evaluating Bluetooth Low Energy. Therefore I have written an Central and Peripheral device application with the Qt framework (5.15). In my case the latency time between messages is important, because of some security aspects. The message size of each command is around 80-100 Bytes. In one of my tests I have sent 80 Bytes commands every 80ms. Ideally the messages should be received  on the other device in 80ms interval as well. For the LAN (TCP) interface this test works well.

For Bluetooth Low Energy I observed that messages, which are sent from Peripheral to Central work quite good and I measured no big delay. Different results I got for the Central to Peripheral direction. Here, I have received the messages in the interval of 100ms to 150ms really exactly. It seems that there couldn’t be a very big magic behind it, so is there any plausible explanation for this? I tested it with a Python script as well and I observed the same results. So it seems that the Qt implementation shouldn’t be the problem.

During research I found out, that the connection interval may influence this, but in Qt the QLowEnergyConnectionParameterRequest (QLowEnergyConnectionParameters Class | Qt Bluetooth 5.15.4) doesn’t work for me. Is there any command, where I can set the connection interval for test purposes at the command line on Linux?

Kind regards, 
BenFR

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your code is slower from central to peripheral because WRITE is used instead of WRITE WITHOUT RESPONSE. The difference is that WRITE waits for an acknowledgement, therefore slowing the communication down, while WRITE WITHOUT RESPONSE is very much like how notifications/indications work in that there's no ACK at the ATT layer. You can change this by changing the [write mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergyservice.html#WriteMode-enum) of your application and ensuring that the peripheral's characteristic supports [WriteNoResponse](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergycharacteristic.html#PropertyType-enum).

Regarding changing the connection interval, the change needs to be accepted from the remote side in order for it to take effect. In other words, if you are requesting the connection parameter change from the peripheral, then the central needs to have code to receive this connection parameter change request and accept it.

Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [How does BLE parameter negotiation work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524971/how-does-ble-parameter-negotiation-work)
- [Understand BLE connection intervals and events](https://www.novelbits.io/ble-connection-intervals/)
- [The different types of BLE write](https://iotexpert.com/ble-write-request-write-command-signed-write-command-prepare-write/)